# Escape HTML only within PRE tag

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Inside my JSP, I simply print out my content as follows:

```
${article.body}
```

Of course, any HTML tags within that object are rendered, and that's expected behaviour. However within this content, I want to show everything within a `<pre>` tag as plain text.

I know HTML can be escaped by using `${fn:escapeXML(article.body)}` or `<c:out value="${article.body}" />`, but that will escape all the HTML, whereas I just need everything inside the `<pre>` tag to be escaped.

I am using Java to generate the contents, and JSP as the view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your could try using jsoup to make the content safe before sending to the jsp.

http://jsoup.org/ allows many levels of escaping.

You code find the  text in your servlet and then send it to be escaped using jsoup or similar.

Comment: The problem with JSoup is that it will lower-case/auto-close any XML tags it deems as malformed. So if I have the example code of: public List<String> methodName() {}, it will actually lowercase and close the <String>, whereas all I want to do is escape it, not parse it.